# Change API_BASEURL

Tags: django

I'm doing a project on Django REST Framework. I need the project to run not on standard "http://127.0.0.1:8000 /", but on the server "http://localhost:8080 ". Please tell me where it needs to be corrected in my project files?

Comment: Partly yes, thanks! I changed manage.py port to 8080 (runserver.default_port = "8080"). But I don't understand how to change 127.0.0.1 to localhost.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 *is* localhost. They are interchangeable, so you can put either one in the browser and get the same result.

Comment: oh, I don't know) Thank you for help!